# How to solve [webpack-cli] TypeError: cli.isMultipleCompiler is not a function

Tags: webpack, webpack-cli

I got stock with with error that I dont understand, I have tried a lot of things like reinstalling all the dependencies but it does not work any idea? Here is the error prompt:

```
No production canister_ids.json found. Continuing with local
[webpack-cli] TypeError: cli.isMultipleCompiler is not a function
    at Command.<anonymous> (/Users/davidmartinezgil/proyect/node_modules/@webpack-cli/serve/lib/index.js:146:35)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (/Users/davidmartinezgil/proyect/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1674:7)
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I had a similar error trying to run a Jhipster app, the error is:

```
[webpack-cli] TypeError: cli.isMultipleCompiler is not a function
at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\doe\folder\MyApp\node_modules\@webpack-cli\serve\lib\index.js:146:35)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async Promise.all (index 1)
at async Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\doe\folder\MyApp\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1674:7)
```

Some suggest to update the **webpack-cli** from *4.9.2* to **4.10.0**

For me works and could run `npm start`

I hope works for you.

[References from webpack issues](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/15951)

Comment: Thank you so much It worked I changed the version inside the package.json to 4.10.0 and then runned "npm i" and it worked perfectly when I used the npm start again thank you.

Comment: Is this a [consequence of Node's _semver_](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/12/16/semantic-versioning)? I have a project that ran a few weeks ago just fine and now with nothing changed it fails due to this. So I imagine it's either a breaking change in transistive dependencies or maybe some kind of external service no longer available?

Answer (score 14):

Ensure you are in your project directory in your terminal

first, type the following in your terminal and hit enter

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
```

then type the following and hit enter:

```
npm upgrade --save-dev webpack-cli
```

it should work

Maybe you will have to do this in every new project you create.

Comment: I was having the same problem and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Here is how you update your webpack-cli for anyone else who was curious.

First, check your version of webpack by running this command in the terminal of your IDE: `webpack --version`. You should see a list that appears like this:

```bash
webpack: 5.71.0
webpack-cli: 4.10.0     
webpack-dev-server 4.8.0
```

If your webpack-cli reads anything below `4.10.0`, then you need to update it to the latest version for npm to run properly on your localhost with JHipster. Here's how to update it.

Run this command in the terminal of your IDE:

```bash
npm install webpack-cli@4.10.0
```

[Right now, the latest version is `4.10.0`, but for the future updates when you run this command, change the version at the end of the command line to updated to that current version:

```bash
npm install webpack-cli@(INSERT NEW VERSION DIGITS HERE).
```

Then re-run `webpack --version`, and see if your webpack has updated to the version that you entered above.

---

EXTRA NOTES:

Why did you have this error? According to `webpack.js.org`: "Note that this is not a recommended practice. Installing globally locks you down to a specific version of webpack and could fail in projects that use a different version."

So, if you ran a command like this: `npm install --global webpack`, then there is a good chance that you were locked down to a specific version. This might have been the error. That's what I believe happened to me anyway. I ran `npm install -g`, or something of that nature.

Sources for your journey and research that relate to the material above:

1. https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/
2. https://stackabuse.com/npm-install-specific-version-of-a-package/

---

Hope this helps! Best of blessings to ya!

Answer (score 1):

Run the below line of code in terminal it will resolve your issue.
If your webpack is below version 4.10.0

1. `npm install webpack-cli@4.10.0`

Answer (score 0):

ensure you are in your project directory in your terminal

Type the following in your terminal and hit enter

npm install webpack-cli

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using yarn then run `yarn add webpack-cli`

Answer (score 0):

Before saying npm start, try writing the code I marked with an asterisk.

1. dfx deploy
2. ***npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
3. npm start

Answer (score 0):

for me it was a easy one
go to your package.json file and change the version from 4.9.x to 4.10
and run npm install
then run npm start again, works like magic!

Answer (score 0):

Install webpack-cli version 4.10

```
npm i webpack-cli@4.10
```

This might work out.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted node_modules and package-lock.json. And then run npm install again.

Answer (score 0):

Update the "webpack-cli" version in the "package-json" to "4.10.0" , and then run "npm install" in your terminal , then run "npm start" . It worked for me just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Update webpack-cli: Make sure you have the latest version of webpack-cli installed. Run the following command to update it:

> npm install webpack-cli@latest

Answer (score 0):

I deleted node_modules, package-lock.json and if there is a build folder, delete that as well and run npm install.
it worked for me